# Pass JSON to JQuery function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-apps-script

We have a very simpel Google Apps Script Web App, which purpose is to show JSON data in a HTML drop-down-list. The JSON file exists in Google Drive. Inspiration code from: http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Mta5b/3/

But when we are trying to 'Fetch Json' no data is loaded in to the dropdown-list:
[image]

## **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <br> <br>
    <center>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>


    <select id="destinations">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
    </center>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
    google.script.run.getJson(); // Runs the function "getJson();" in Code.gs

    $('#fetch').click(function(s) {

        $.post(s, {json: JSON.stringify(json)}, function(data) {
            $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
                $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## **Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
      var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

      var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

      return htmlOutput;
    }

    function getJson() {

    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("jsonData.json");
      var file = files.next();
      var JSONDATA = file.getAs("application/json").getDataAsString();
      //JSONDATA = JSON.stringify(JSONDATA);
      JSONDATA = JSON.parse(JSONDATA);
      Logger.log(JSONDATA);

    click(JSONDATA); // <-- Trying to pass this data to "$('#fetch').click(function(s) {"
    }
```

## **jsonData.json**

```
{
        "options": {    
           "Destinations": [
        {
            "destinationName": "London",
            "destinationID": "lon"
        },
        {
            "destinationName": "New York",
            "destinationID": "nyc"
        },
        {
            "destinationName": "Paris",
            "destinationID": "par"
        },
        {
            "destinationName": "Rome",
            "destinationID": "rom"
        }
        ]
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the data in `getJson()` function, and when calling it, you need to pass a callback, with `withSuccessHandler()`, as such:

in HTML:

```
function justLog(e){
   console.log(e);
}

$('#fetch').click(function(s) {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(justLog).getJson(); // Runs the function "getJson();" in Code.gs
});
```

in code.gs, finish the function with:

```
return JSONDATA;
```

Comment: Kriggs you were right, i needed a syccesshandler, i re-coded what i needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kriggs! This worked out great:

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <select id="dropDownDest">
</select>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

function onSuccess(json) {

       $.each(json.Cars, function (key, value) {
            $("#dropDownDest").append($('<option></option>').val(value.carID).html(value.CarType));
        });

        $('#dropDownDest').change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            //Code to select image based on selected car id
        });

      }

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .jsonData();

    </script>

  </head>
</html>
```

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

    function jsonData() {

     var a = {
                Cars: [{
                    "CarType": "BMW",
                    "carID": "bmw123"
                }, {
                    "CarType": "mercedes",
                    "carID": "merc123"
                }, {
                    "CarType": "volvo",
                    "carID": "vol123r"
                }, {
                    "CarType": "ford",
                    "carID": "ford123"
                }]
            }; 

      Logger.log(a);
      return a;

    }
```